# How to create a list of lists using Range[]

Tags: list-manipulation

Given an integer, say 20, how can I create the following irregular list of lists?

```
lst={5,7,3,5};
Range[#]&/@lst;
```

generates this:

```
{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}
```

I like to have the following list of lists:

```
{{1,2,3,4,5}, {6,7,8,9,10,11,12}, {13,14,15}, {16,17,18,19,20}}
```

If the list of lists was a regular sequence, I could use:

```
Partition[Range[20], 5]]
```

Comment: `TakeList[Range@ Total@(a = {5, 7, 3, 5}), a]`

Comment: Or `TakeList[Range@Total@#,#]&@lst`

Comment: `Range[#]&/@lst;` could be `Range/@lst;`

Comment: @AsukaMinato Or `Range@lst`!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
lst = {5, 7, 3, 5};
```

1. First way:

We have

```
Internal`PartitionRagged[Range@20, lst]
```

2. Another one

We have

```
TakeList[Range@20, lst]
```

The output is:

> [image: list]

Answer (score 13):

This is the classic use-case for `FoldPairList`:

```
FoldPairList[TakeDrop, Range[20], {5, 7, 3, 5}]
```

Alternatively, I recently made a [resource function](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/SplitAtPositions/) for the situation where you want to split at specific positions:

```
ResourceFunction["SplitAtPositions"][Range[20], {5, 12, 15}, After]
```

Comment: Congrats on the `SplitAtPositions`. I will keep that in mind :-)

Answer (score 6):

Although `TakeList` is the built-in function to do this, but if you want to do it randomly then a bit of setup would be helpful:

```
n = 20; (* list length *)
k = 5; (* # parts of list *)
alist = Range[n]
parts = IntegerPartitions[n, {k}]
SeedRandom[1];
TakeList[alist, RandomChoice[parts]]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {11, 12, 13, 14}, {15, 16, 17, 
>   18}, {19, 20}}
> ```

Answer (score 6):

Sightly long.

```
lst={5,7,3,5};
len = Total@lst;
index = Accumulate[lst];
diff = Join[{{1,lst[[1]]}}, Transpose[{index[[;;-2]]+1, index[[2;;]]}]];
(Range@len)[[#1;;#2]]&@@@diff
```

Answer (score 5):

Starting from your two lines:

```
lst = {5, 7, 3, 5};
ints = Range[#] & /@ lst;

ints + Flatten[{0, Drop[Accumulate[lst], -1]}]
{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15}, {16, 17, 18, 19, 20}}
```

Answer (score 5):

We create a `RangePartition` function:

```
RangePartition[list_List] := MapAt[{#[[1]] + 1, #[[2]]} &, Partition[Flatten[Append[{1}, Accumulate[list]]], 2, 1], Outer[List, Range[2, Length[list]]]]
```

Also, we create a `RangeList` function:

```
RangeList[list_List] := Block[{arraysymb, symb, rangesymb,rangelist},
arraysymb = Array[Subscript[symb, ##] &, 2, 1];
rangesymb = Array[Subscript[symb, ##] &, 2, 1, HoldForm[Range]];
rangelist = 
ReleaseHold[ReplaceAll[Thread[arraysymb -> list]][rangesymb]];
Return[rangelist]]
```

Then:

```
Map[RangeList, RangePartition[lst]]

(*{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15}, {16, 17, 18,19, 20}}*)
```

Answer (score 3):

Further alternatives:

```
ClearAll[f, g, h]

f = FoldList[#2 + Last @ # &] @* Range;

g = Range @ # + Prepend[0] @ Most @ Accumulate @ # &;

h = Total @* Through @* {Range, Prepend[0] @* Most @* Accumulate}
```

***Examples:***

```
f @ lst
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15}, {16, 17, 18, 19, 20}}
> ```

```
f @ lst == g @ lst == h @ lst
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: so happy to have seen this answer for two reasons. 1. we did the tenfold way **AGAIN** and 2. well...it's an answer by you. Do I need more than that? Nicely done!!!